# Ads not loaded error after creating billing account

Tags: android, admob

I am creating an app. For last ten days, `admob` banner ad was working fine. Yesterday I created a `billing account` to use `Places SDK`. From that point, I am not getting any ads and logcat showing ads failed to load. Actually it fails to connect to `firebase` as well. Just to be sure, I have reinstalled `google-services.json` also, with no change.

```
 I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 0
 I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 0
 E/FirebaseCrashlytics: Create report HTTP request failed.
 E/FirebaseCrashlytics: Error occurred sending report com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.report.model.SessionReport@8c8b9c3
 E/FirebaseCrashlytics: Create report HTTP request failed.
 E/FirebaseCrashlytics: Error occurred sending report com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.report.model.SessionReport@5e2b240
 E/FirebaseCrashlytics: Create report HTTP request failed.
 E/FirebaseCrashlytics: Error occurred sending report com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.report.model.SessionReport@1559579
 E/FirebaseCrashlytics: Create report HTTP request failed.
 E/FirebaseCrashlytics: Error occurred sending report com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.report.model.SessionReport@991b2be
 I/Ads: This request is sent from a test device.
```

As long as I am using an apk created before creating the billing account, ads are there. But with apk created after creating the billing account, there is no ad, and this info/warning is coming.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the emulator lost internet connection. Just reseted it and now all is fine